# CNN features(dimensions) feed to LSTM Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, convolution

So recently i am working on a project which i am supposed to take images as input to a CNN and extract the features and feed them to LSTM for training. I am using 2 Layer CNN for feature extraction and im taking the features form fully connected layer and trying to feed them to LSTM. Problem is when i want to feed the FC layer to LSTM as input i get error regarding to wrong dimension. my FC layer is a Tensor with (128,1024) dimension. I tried to reshape it like this tf.reshape(fc,[-1]) which gives me a tensor ok (131072, )
dimension and still wont work. Could anyone give me any ideas of how im suppose to feed the FC to LSTM?here i just write part of my code and teh error i get.

Convolution Layer with 32 filters and a kernel size of 5

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 32, 5, activation=tf.nn.relu)
# Max Pooling (down-sampling) with strides of 2 and kernel size of 2
conv1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1, 2, 2)

# Convolution Layer with 32 filters and a kernel size of 5
conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, 64, 3, activation=tf.nn.relu)
# Max Pooling (down-sampling) with strides of 2 and kernel size of 2
conv2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv2, 2, 2)

# Flatten the data to a 1-D vector for the fully connected layer
fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(conv2)

# Fully connected layer (in contrib folder for now)
fc1 = tf.layers.dense(fc1, 1024)
# Apply Dropout (if is_training is False, dropout is not applied)
fc1 = tf.layers.dropout(fc1, rate=dropout, training=is_training)
s = tf.reshape(fc1, [1])
rnn_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)
outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(rnn_cell, s, dtype=tf.float32)
return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], rnn_weights['out']) + rnn_biases['out']
```

here is the error:
ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 131072 elements to shape [1] (1 elements) for 'ConvNet/Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [128,1024], [1] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [1].

Answer (score 3):

You have a logical error in how you approach the problem. Collapsing the data to a 1D tensor is not going to solve anything (even if you get it to work correctly).

If you are taking a sequence of images as input your input tensor should be 5D (batch, sequence_index, x, y, channel) or something permutation like that. conv2d should complain about the extra dimension but you probably missing one of them. You should try to fix it first.

Next use conv3d and max_pool3d with a window of 1 for the depth (since you don't want the different frames to interact at this stage).

When you are done you should still have 5D tensor, but x and y dimensions should be 1 (you should check this, and fix the operation if that's not the case).

The RNN part expects 3D tensors (batch, sequence_index, fature_index). You can use tf.squeeze to remove the 1 sized dimensions from your 5D tensor and get this 3D tensor. You shouldn't have to reshape anything.

If you don't use batches, it's OK, but the operations will still expect the dimension to be there (but for you it will be 1). Missing the dimension will cause problems with shapes down the line.